# Yet another Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working - Android

Tags: android, list, listview, adapter

I have been using a method to populate an adapter like the following:

1. Set the UI components in a custom method inside `onCreate(...)`

```
//..
mRecentSales = new ArrayList<>();
        recentSaleAdapter = new RecentSaleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_recent_sale, mRecentSales);
        lvRecentSales.setAdapter(recentSaleAdapter);
//.
```

2. Load in a different thread the data for the adapter just after `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onLoadingPrepare() {
    super.onLoadingPrepare();
    if (qDaySales == null)
        qDaySales = new ArrayList<>();
    else
        qDaySales.clear();
    if (mRecentSales == null)
        mRecentSales = new ArrayList<>();
    else
        mRecentSales.clear();
}

@Override
public void onLoading() {
    super.onLoading();
    todayIncome = Conversor.asCurrency(presenter.getDaySales());
    performance = presenter.getImprovement(getApplicationContext());
    for (int i = 1; i<= DateTime.now().getDayOfMonth(); i++){
        qDaySales.add(new Entry(i, presenter.getSalesFromDay(i)));
    }
    mRecentSales.addAll(presenter.getRecentSales());
}

@Override
public void onLoadingComplete() {
    super.onLoadingComplete();
    tvTodayIncome.setText(todayIncome);
    tvPerformance.setText(performance);
    setPerformanceChart(qDaySales);
    recentSaleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the Adapter code:

```
public class RecentSaleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MTicket> {

public RecentSaleAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recent_sale, null);
    }
    MTicket ticket = getItem(position);
    TextView tvTicketId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticket_id);
    TextView tvTicketReference = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticket_reference);
    TextView tvTicketTotal = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticket_total);
    if (ticket != null){
        tvTicketId.setText(String.format("# %d", ticket.id));
        tvTicketReference.setText(ticket.ticketReference);
        tvTicketTotal.setText(ticket.maskSaleTotal);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    MTicket ticket = getItem(position);
    if (ticket != null)
        return ticket.id;
    return -1;
}
```

}

The result is not what I've expected since the List does not shows anything.

Comment: You should post the code of your adapter.

Comment: Debug your code and make sure before `recentSaleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  `mRecentSales` filled with data or not .

Comment: Been doing that for the last days. The size of it changes as expected afteer method `onLoading()`

Comment: Debug your code. After you get with the debugger past the line mRecentSales.addAll(presenter.getRecentSales()); check the *objects* field in your adapter and see if you have the elements there. If they aren't there but the items are present in mRecentSales, review the use of mRecentSales and make sure there is only one reference of this list.

Comment: After the additional step. I Can confirm that `recentSalesAdapter` also changes when the objects are loaded to `recentSales.addAll(presenter.getRecentSales())`. I'm starting to think this is a bug from the Android Platform

Comment: Keep  in mind that ArrayAdapter is a basic implementation of a ListAdapter suitable for simple uses.It has an add() method that you should use(to append items to it), if you need more control extending BaseAdapter might be more appropriate. Also, you should call notifyDataSetChanged() right after you update the list.(Just for testing, try removing the code which clears the mRecentSales list and see how it goes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up givin' up with Async Tasks.

There seems to be a bug with it and Android just won't handle properly the callbacks.

This is the resulting workaround:

1. Instead of populating the object list inside the `onLoading()` method, I just call all of the needed methods in the main thread.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       setTitle(getPreferenceString(SettingsActivity.KEY_BUSINESS_NAME,
           getString(R.string.set_default_business_name)));
       start(); // <- This will start the Async Task
       mRecentSales.clear();
       mRecentSales.addAll(presenter.getRecentSales());
       recentSaleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```